# Bootstrap carousel without arrows and auto slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I am trying to get an **auto-slide carousel with 2 activ/showing images and without arrows** like on this page (the brand-logos on the right, if you scroll down a few px): http://www.videoboost.de/#anfrage

Unfortunately I couldnt find a solution. Thats my current code, which isnt working of course, as the data-target was for pressing the arrows. Could you please help me or give any advising hint? Thank you very much!

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
</head> <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/JPmorgan.png" alt="b" height="71">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/rheinland-logo.png" alt="c" height="71">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/BarmerGEK.png" alt="d" height="71">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a few problems in your code--

- you forgot to close `head` tag.
- you didn't add `jquery` and `bootstrap js` these are required libraries to make carousel working.
- to show two images in a carousel slide use bootstrap responsive classes. in the following way--

  ```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
  </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
       <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
       </div>
       </div>
  ```

**Working Snippet**

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head> <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
    </div>
    
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/JPmorgan.png" alt="b" height="71">
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/rheinland-logo.png" alt="c" height="71">
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/bmw-logo.png" alt="a" height="71">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/BarmerGEK.png" alt="d" height="71">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="http://www.videoboost.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/BarmerGEK.png" alt="d" height="71">
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!